# Exponential of a complex line

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there an "elementary" way to prove that if $D$ is a one-dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{C}$ (considered here as a real vector space), then $\exp(D) \neq \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What counts as elementary?

The restriction of $\exp$ to any subset whose diameter is smaller than $2\pi$ is injective, so for every compact "interval" $I \subset D$ whose length is smaller than $2\pi$, $\exp\lvert_I$ is a homeomorphism. In particular, $\exp(I)$ has empty interior. $D$ is the union of countably many compact intervals of length $5$ (arbitrary choice $< 2\pi$), so $\exp(D)$ is the union of countably many closed subsets of $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ with empty interior. Hence $\exp(D)$ is of the first category in $\mathbb{C}^\ast$, hence its complement is dense.

$\exp$ is a local diffeomorphism, hence $\exp(D)$ is a one-dimensional (real) submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^\ast$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I didn't think of restricting $\exp$ to a "small domain" so that it becomes a homeomorphism.