# Show that a complex map is onto

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space. For $(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}$, consider the map : $F_{a,b} \, ; \, \mathbb{C} \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ such that :

$$ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \; F_{a,b}(z) = \exp \big( a \Re(z) + b \Im(z) \big). $$

where $\Re(z)$ (resp. $\Im(z)$) are respectively the real and imaginary part of $z$.

I would like to prove that the map $F_{a,b}$ is onto if and only if $\mathrm{Span}(a,b) = \mathbb{C}$.

If $\mathrm{dim} \, \mathrm{Span}(a,b) = 1$ then $\mathrm{Span}(a,b)$ is a complex line $D$ and $F_{a,b}(\mathbb{C}) = \exp(D)$ but it does not seem easy to prove that $\exp(D) \neq \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ without topological arguments. (see [Exponential of a complex line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585106/exponential-of-a-complex-line))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=a_1+ia_2$, $\>b=b_1+i b_2$. Your map $F_{a,b}$ can be written as
$$F_{a,b}=\exp \>\circ\> T\ .$$
Here $$T:\>{\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb C}, \qquad z\mapsto a\>{\rm Re}(z)+b\>{\rm Im}(z)$$ can be considered as a real linear  map $$T:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad (x,y)\mapsto(a_1x+b_1y, \>a_2x+b_2 y)$$
with matrix
$$\bigl[T\bigr]=\left[\matrix{a_1 &b_1 \cr a_2 & b_2\cr}\right]\ .$$
When $$\det T=a_1b_2-a_2b_1={\rm Im}(a\>b)\ne0$$
then $T$ is nonsingular and maps ${\mathbb R}^2$ onto ${\mathbb R}^2$, resp. ${\mathbb C}$ onto ${\mathbb C}$. In this case $F_{a,b}$ is surjective, since $\exp:\>{\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb C}^*$ is surjective.

When ${\rm Im}(a\>b)=0$, but $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$ then $T$ has rank $1$ and maps ${\mathbb R}^2$ onto a line through the origin. Depending on the slope of this line the image set of $F_{a,b}$ will then be a ray, a logarithmic spiral, or a circle.

When $a=b=0$ then $F_{a,b}({\mathbb C})=\{1\}$.